# PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH other than 8

Tags: c, pcre

I have the following `pcre2` import which I use as a sort of placeholder/default:

```
/* The PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH macro must be defined before including pcre2.h.
For a program that uses only one code unit width, setting it to 8, 16, or 32
makes it possible to use generic function names such as pcre2_compile(). */

#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include <pcre2.h>
```

In what cases would the code-width not be 8? For example, on non-asci/utf-8 characters, should the code-width be set to 16 or 8? What are the most common usages of having a non-8-bit-width?

Answer (score 2):

In case others stumble on this old question looking for the answer.

It's not a question of whether your pattern(s) and/or subject(s) contain unicode characters, but what underlying data type you use. Are you using regular C strings (8-bit char pointers) or something like `wchar_t` or `char16_t`? Then you must use the matching PCRE2 code unit width.

The example below illustrates this. Both `char*` and `char16_t*` work just fine with the same pattern and subjects containing unicode, but trying to use the wrong PCRE2 code unit width will cause segmentation faults at worst and wrong results at best (or perhaps that's worse, because you might not notice).

(This code intentionally leaves out some checks and stuff you'd probably want to do, so please don't use it as an example of how to properly use PCRE2.)

```
// gcc -Wall pcrecuw.c -o pcrecuw -lpcre2-8 -lpcre2-16
#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 0

#include <stdio.h>
#include <uchar.h>
#include <pcre2.h>

int main() {
    pcre2_code_8* re8, *re8x ;
    pcre2_code_16* re16, *re16x ;
    pcre2_match_data_8* match_data8 ;
    pcre2_match_data_16* match_data16 ;
    int errornumber ;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroroffset ;
    int rc, i ;

    // Create two versions (8- and 16-bit) of the same pattern and subjects.
    // The pattern matches the first two subjects but not the third.
    char* pattern8 = "l(o|ö)" ;
    char* subject8[] = {"hello", "hellö", "hellô"} ;

    char16_t* pattern16 = u"l(o|ö)" ;
    char16_t* subject16[] = {u"hello", u"hellö", u"hellô"} ;

    // Length of the pattern in *code units*, without the final \0
    int lenp8 = 7 ;
    int lenp16 = 6 ;

    // Length of the subjects in *code units*, without the final \0
    int lens8[] = {5, 6, 6} ;
    int lens16[] = {5, 5, 5} ;

    // Convert these to PCRE strings in four different ways:

    // PCRE_8 with 8-bit strings (Correct)
    PCRE2_SPTR8 r_pattern8 = (PCRE2_SPTR8)pattern8 ;
    PCRE2_SPTR8 r_subject8[] = {
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject8[0],
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject8[1],
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject8[2]
    } ;
    
    // PCRE_16 with 16-bit strings (Correct)
    PCRE2_SPTR16 r_pattern16 = (PCRE2_SPTR16)pattern16 ;
    PCRE2_SPTR16 r_subject16[] = {
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject16[0],
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject16[1],
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject16[2]
    } ;

    // PCRE_8 with 16-bit strings (Wrong)
    PCRE2_SPTR8 r_pattern8x = (PCRE2_SPTR8)pattern16 ;
    PCRE2_SPTR8 r_subject8x[] = {
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject16[0],
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject16[1],
        (PCRE2_SPTR8)subject16[2]
    } ;
    
    // PCRE_16 with 8-bit strings (Wrong)
    PCRE2_SPTR16 r_pattern16x = (PCRE2_SPTR16)pattern8 ;
    PCRE2_SPTR16 r_subject16x[] = {
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject8[0],
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject8[1],
        (PCRE2_SPTR16)subject8[2]
    } ;

    // Compile
    re8 = pcre2_compile_8(
        r_pattern8, lenp8, PCRE2_UTF, &errornumber, &erroroffset, NULL
    ) ;
    re16 = pcre2_compile_16(
        r_pattern16, lenp16, PCRE2_UTF, &errornumber, &erroroffset, NULL
    ) ;
    // Note that we use the true lengths of the underlying strings in the second 
    // argument. It doesn't actually matter, however, since we get the wrong 
    // results (or errors) anyway.
    re8x = pcre2_compile_8(
        r_pattern8x, lenp16, PCRE2_UTF, &errornumber, &erroroffset, NULL
    ) ;
    re16x = pcre2_compile_16(
        r_pattern16x, lenp8, PCRE2_UTF, &errornumber, &erroroffset, NULL
    ) ;

    match_data8 = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_8(re8, NULL) ;
    match_data16 = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_16(re16, NULL) ;
    // Note that we can't even create match data for re8x and re16x without 
    // segmentation faults. If we didn't have the correct versions, we would be 
    // stuck at this point. By reusing the correct ones, we'll get the wrong 
    // results, but at least the code will run.

    // Matching 8 with 8 (Correct)
    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        rc = pcre2_match_8(
            re8, r_subject8[i], lens8[i], 0, 0, match_data8, NULL
        ) ;
        printf("Subject #%d: %s\n", i, ((rc >= 0) ? "Match!" : "No match!")) ;
    }
    printf("\n") ;
    
    // Matching 16 with 16 (Correct)
    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        rc = pcre2_match_16(
            re16, r_subject16[i], lens16[i], 0, 0, match_data16, NULL
        ) ;
        printf("Subject #%d: %s\n", i, ((rc >= 0) ? "Match!" : "No match!")) ;
    }
    printf("\n") ;

    // Matching 8 with 16 (Wrong)
    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        rc = pcre2_match_8(
            re8x, r_subject8x[i], lens16[i], 0, 0, match_data8, NULL
        ) ;
        printf("Subject #%d: %s\n", i, ((rc >= 0) ? "Match!" : "No match!")) ;
    }
    printf("\n") ;
    
    // Matching 16 with 8 (Wrong)
    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        rc = pcre2_match_16(
            re16x, r_subject16x[i], lens8[i], 0, 0, match_data16, NULL
        ) ;
        printf("Subject #%d: %s\n", i, ((rc >= 0) ? "Match!" : "No match!")) ;
    }

    pcre2_match_data_free_8(match_data8) ;
    pcre2_match_data_free_16(match_data16) ;

    pcre2_code_free_8(re8) ;
    pcre2_code_free_16(re16) ;
    pcre2_code_free_8(re8x) ;
    pcre2_code_free_16(re16x) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```